# XML file with CDATA values that contain multiple columns and records

Tags: xml, cdata

I'm having difficulty reading an XML file with CDATA values that contain multiple columns and records instead of usual markup entries as seen below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UT32"?>
      <S:Env xmlns:S="http://soap.org/">
        <S:Body>
          <ns2:request xmlns:ns2="http://ris.com/">
            <arg0>
              <item>
                <name>IDVAR_SMLORT</name>
                <value> Beckumerstr./Beckenfarderweg ,  59302  Oelde</value>
              </item>
              <item>
                <name>IDVAR_SMLJAHR</name>
                <value>16</value>
              </item>
              <item>
                <name>IDVAR_MATRIX</name>
                <value><![CDATA[<Matrix version="1">
                  <Items>
                    <item id="i1" name="Code"/>
                    <item id="i2" name="Date"/>
                  </Items>
                  <Infos>
                    <Info no="1">
                      <Value itemId="i1">ZW</Value>
                      <Value itemId="i2">2016-03-22</Value>
                    </Info>
                    <Info no="2">
                      <Value itemId="i1">8502647794</Value>
                      <Value itemId="i2">EMAILG</Value>
                    </Info>
                    <Info no="3">
                      <Value itemId="i1">8502647794</Value>
                      <Value itemId="i2">TELP</Value>
                    </Info>
                  <Infos>
                </Matrix>
                ]]></value>
              </item>
            </arg0>
          </ns2:request>
        </S:Body>
      </S:Env>
```

And this is the SQL statement I use to read the xmlfile above:

```
    SELECT ExtractValue( Value(p), '/item/name/text()')  as IdvarName,
           ExtractValue( Value(p), '/item/value/text()') as IdvarValue
    FROM   Table( XMLSequence (Extract( xmlFile, '/arg0/item' ))) p )
```

The XML file above has atleast 3 records. The first two are straight forward data but the last one is complex. It first defines the columns/fieldnames. Afterwards it takes multiples records. I'm able to read the first two but not the third one. Also, I notice that if I keep the URL address in the XML file, I can't read file and would result either runtime time error or no data found. But if I remove it, the SQL statement works alright.

I'm already out of deep here. What should I change in my SQL statement to generate the result I needed? Can please someone help me? Thanks